# Step definition from multiple files for same scenario

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a scenario where its step definitions resides in multiple files. For instance the login step resides in login_steps.rb and a search related step resides in search_steps.rb

Cucumber outputs undefined steps for any step that is not in login_steps.rb. The step definitions are run only when its present in login_steps.rb. Is it required to place all the step definitions of a scenario in the same file?

My folder structure

```
Project folder
└─ features
   ├─ pages
   ├─ scenarios 
   ├─ step_definitions
   └─ support
```

Command I used:

```
cucumber -r features features\scenarios\Test.feature
```

Comment: what happens if you move the `step_definitions` folder inside scenarios folder?

Comment: it is still the same result

Comment: I got it working. There were some hidden files with same name as the step definition files. I just removed them.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point to Cucumber and the POM is that you have flexibility and do not need to re-write your steps per feature file. This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
Root
 - features
   - step_definitions
     - step_definition.rb
   - support
      - env.rb
 - lib
  - BasePage.rb
 - feature.feature
```

Basically, with this directory structure, it doesn't matter where your step definitions are AS LONG AS YOU REQUIRE THE SPECIFIC PAGE YOU'RE REFERENCING (your BasePage.rb file, for example)

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'lib', 'pages', 'BasePage')


And /^I do something$/ do
  @page = BasePage.new(@test_env)
  @page.verify_el(css)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specifics of RoR and cucumber, but I do use cucumber-jvm.  Using steps from different files is supported.  Note the documentation https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Cucumber-Backgrounder#where-do-i-put-tests specifically mentions it.

Sorry I can't be more help with the specific issue, but what you are trying to do (use step from different files) is workable.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a "violation" but I would combine the answers from Whitney Imura and Dave W just to make the answer more clear...

You ask:

> "Is it required to place all the step 
>   definitions of a scenario in the same file?"

**No.** You can place your step definitions in *logically distinct files within various folders*, as you see fit (example below). After all, it is just ruby code.

Essentially Your command is correct for running an individual feature that has step definitions in various other folders...

```
cucumber -r features features\entities\entity.feature
```

If you do not run it as above, you will get missing stepdefs... Here I execute tests on a current project as a means to demonstrate:

```
cucumber
60 scenarios (14 undefined, 46 passed)
409 steps (32 skipped, 26 undefined, 351 passed)

cucumber -r features
60 scenarios (60 passed)
409 steps (409 passed)
```

---

As described in the [Cucumber documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Cucumber-Backgrounder#where-do-i-put-tests), you can arrange your tests to suite your logical breakdown of your features:

```
|__ features
|   |__ entities
|   |   |__ entity.feature
|   |   |__ step_definitions
|   |       |__ anything.rb
|   |       |__ entity_steps.rb
|   |__ locations
|   |   |__ location.feature
|   |   |__ step_definitions
|   |       |__location_steps.rb
|   |__ sites
|   |   |__ step_definitions
|   |__ step_definitions
|   |   |__ local_assert_steps.rb
|   |   |__ local_crud_response_steps.rb
|   |   |__ local_email_steps.rb
|   |   |__ local_file_steps.rb
|   |   |__ local_script_steps.rb
|   |   |__ local_steps.rb
|   |   |__ local_web_steps.rb
`   |   |__ local_xml_file_steps.rb   
    |__ support
        |__ env.rb
        |__ local_env.rb
        |__ local_transforms.rb
```